# Using jQuery, show a div if only two or more checkboxes are checked

Tags: jquery

I need to show a div if two or more checkboxes are checked using JQuery only.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

```
if($('input:checked').length >= 2) {
   $('div').show();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

jQuery:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').change(function(){
        if($('input:checked').size() > 1){
         $("div").show();   
    }
    else {
         $('div').hide()   
    }
})
```

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="one"></input>
<input type="checkbox" id="one"></input>
<input type="checkbox" id="one"></input>
<div style="display: none;">At least 2 are checked</div>
```

[Try it!](http://jsfiddle.net/adamzr/jkR2h/)